# Converting this 3d array into 2d array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to convert the following 3D array into a 2D array. Currently, my data has the following structure.

```
[ [[0,0,345], [1,0,555], ... [9,0,333]], ... [[0,9,1000], [1,9,987], ... [9,9,129]] ]
```

into

```
[[0,0,345], [1,0,355], ... [9,0,333], [0,1,1000], [1,1,987], ... [9,9,129]]
```

so the first element contains a width value, and the second is the height value. The third value will be a random value from 0 to 1023.

As you see, the width and height will be 10 each. And I am trying to get rid of the outermost array.

I have tried to iterate for each row to bounce to a new array using push, but keep getting undesired forms. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: what do you want the comma to mean between the two array you list? or is your example wrong and you actually just want a flat array of "points" (three-value arrays)?

Comment: You were right @ChristianFritz, I have now edited. Each array means each sensor with its x and y value and pressure value at the end. I want all the sensors (so far we have 100) to be inside one mother array.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge/flatten an array of arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865025/merge-flatten-an-array-of-arrays)

Comment: this question has been asked before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly use `Array#flat`.

```js
const arr = [ [[0,0,345], [1,0,555], [9,0,333]],  [[0,9,1000], [1,9,987], [9,9,129]] ];
const res = arr.flat();
console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this flatmap. Example below.

```
let data = [[["creative fee (example)"], [1000]], [["Item 1...", "Item 2..."], [600, 1000]], [["Item 3...", "Item 4..."], [400, 600]]],
    result = data.flatMap(([l, r]) => l.map((v, i) => [v, r[i]]));

console.log(result);
```